# How to set Overdue, Not Valid in php?

Tags: php

I have a problem to define a product which have a expiry date. I want to set a product which it **not valid** (when `$now = date("d-M-y")` *more than* `$valid = date("d-M-y", strtotime('+'.$day.' days',strtotime($date)));`),

**overdue** (when `$now = date("d-M-y")` *more than* `$due = date("d-M-y", strtotime('-30 days',strtotime($valid)));` and `$now = date("d-M-y")` *less than* `$valid = date("d-M-y", strtotime('+'.$day.' days',strtotime($date)));`)

**valid** (when `$now = date("d-M-y")` *less than* `$valid = date("d-M-y", strtotime('+'.$day.' days',strtotime($date)));`)

This is my code :

```
if ($due > $now && $now > $valid )
{
$vendor ='<td style="color:red;text-align: center;font-weight: bold">'.$rowpur['ven_code'].' (Overdue)</td>';   
}
elseif ($due > $now && $now < $valid )
{
$vendor ='<td style="color:red;text-align: center;font-weight: bold">'.$rowpur['ven_code'].' (Not Valid)</td>'; 
}       
else 
{
$vendor = '<td style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold">'.$rowpur['ven_code'].'</td>';  
}
```

And the result like a screenshot :

[image]

But all that vendor code must be **Not Valid**

Comment: Be careful with the names you choose. A name like `valid` probably implies a boolean value, something is either valid or not. It certainly doesn't imply a date. A better name would have been `validUntil`. You also mix `due` and `overdue`, which don't mean the same thing.

Comment: If you want to compare dates in string form, then they need to be in a properly sortable format. `d-M-y` isn’t one - because string comparison happens character by character, from left to right - so the day would be the first “criterion” here, and that means `21-Jul-15` would be considered “greater” than `07-Jul-19`. And the month _names_ are not suitable for proper sorting at all. If you want to sort/compare dates as strings, then you need to use a format like YYYY-MM-DD or similar.

Comment: @misorude, I choose your option.Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare dates via the basic < and >. The reason being that they are objects. You can represent the dates by calling the timestamp() method on the object. This will return an integer which can be compared the classical way.

Comment: You might want to also mention using date_diff https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php on the actual date objects as well.

Comment: You can compare php DateTime objects. But I think these are strings (the result of `date`, right?), which are not working as expected.

Comment: @Nanne This is indeed a more accurate explanation. Thank you.